# HttpClient GetStringAsync results are inconsistent

Tags: c#, web-scraping, httpclient

I have a very simple console application where the user can enter the name of a Twitch user to see if a Twitch profile with that name exists. Here is the code:

```
while (true)
{
    string username = Console.ReadLine();

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string result = await client.GetStringAsync($"https://www.twitch.tv/{username}");

    Console.WriteLine("User exists: " + !result.Contains("Twitch is the world"));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The text "Twitch is the world" will only exists within the result if the provided url doesn't lead to an existing profile. The issue I'm having is that the HttpClient only seem to return the "right" result the first time around. For example, I start the program and enter "xqc". This will give me the result

```
User exists: True
```

However, if I now try to enter "xqc" again (or any other existing profile name for that matter) it will always result in the following result

```
User exists: False
```

I checked the actual string and the reason it's happening is because, for some reason, every request made after the first one will return Twitch's profile not found page. I don't see why this would happen. Is there something I'm missing or is there something else I should use here instead of HttpClient?

Comment: This is an highly unreliable way to check if a channel exists. You should instead use [the official Twitch API](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#search-channels).

Comment: Why are you "blocking" at the end of the while loop (`ReadKey()`) when you just block again at the start of the loop (`ReadLine()`)?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel The Twitch API requires OAuth, something that I am very unfamiliar with. Apparently I need to register my app to receive an access token. The registration page also need me to provide a "redirect URL" for the OAuth. That seems like a lot of work just for a simple console app meant to simply say if a twitch user exists or not. Furthermore I don't really get how I'm supposed to get a redirect URL when my application don't have an URL in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Console.ReadKey()` is consuming the first character of your input, so the second time the string username will not contain "xqc", but "qc".

Comment: How do I prevent it from doing that?

Comment: What do you need that line for? If you remove it the program works as expected.

Comment: `ReadLine()` already blocks for input, so just remove the `ReadKey()` and it'll work.